# Why did Thoros of Myr say "Funny old life"?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones season 7 episode 6 During an epic expedition in the North, the red priest Thoros of Myr

> is attacked and injured by a wight bear. Then he says to Beric Dondarion "I just got bit by a dead bear" and adds "**Funny old life**".

Does this remark have a special meaning?

If it were Jorah I could see how it's funny since he comes from Bear Island, but I don't remember any mention of bears in relation to Thoros. Anything in the books maybe?

Comment: I think the funny thing is that it was dead, not that it was a bear.

Comment: Well, it can bee ironic that after beeing "killed" several time, and resurrected each time, his final death come from an undead bear

Comment: No there's nothing which links bears and Thoros in books.

Comment: @Kepotx I think you're mixing up Thoros and Beric there.

Comment: I agree with Master Scott, I'd assume it was because the bear was "undead" and he's been bringing people back from the dead

Comment: @Edlothiad Thanks for the clarification, I didn't understand Mike Scott's comment at first. Kind of makes sense now.

Comment: @Kepotx Thoros had never died and been resurrected. That was Beric. He's saying it as a comment on their life and adventures. They've both done many wild and crazy things, and being bitten by a dead bear is one to the add to the list. Funny old life isn't it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### It's just an ironic expression of how messed up the world has become

Being a member of the Priesthood worshipping the Lord of Fire as well as a member of the Brotherhood Without Banners, Thoros has seen some sh*t!

He's witnessed and performed the re-animation of this friend Beric Dondarrion from death, and has encountered other dead things walking, like the bear that should have been dead.

[image: A flaming un-dead polar bear attacking in a rage]
<sup>[img src](http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/599b097dd0302032925230e9-1632/zombie-bear-got.png)</sup>

He's saying "[it's a] funny old life" because it really *isn't*. It's funny, in that it's *strange*; that's it, no more to it.

---

Additionally, none of this stuff happens in the books, so I can't give any extra information. Only that there is no explicit relation or connection between Thoros and bears.

Comment: “none of this stuff happens in the books” — *YET!*

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Dead bears walking and killing stuff has happened in the books. As to the Suicide Squad going out to get one o' them dead lads, it most likely will never happen in the books. At least I hope it won't.

Comment: Beric, for one, is fully dead on the books, so it's unlikely to happen as in the show.